# How to Merge Array of Document in Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have this document in Mongo DB:

```
[
  {
    "alphabet": ['A', 'B', 'C']
  },
  {
    "alphabet": ['D', 'E', 'F']
  },
  {
    "alphabet": ['G', 'H', 'I']
  }
]
```

Which I get from this query

```
db.tc_example.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            alphabet: 1
        }
    }
])
```

How to merge the documents into one document like this?

```
{
  "alphabet": [
    ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    ['D', 'E', 'F'],
    ['G', 'H', 'I']
  ]
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below aggregation

```
db.tc_example.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "alphabet": { "$push": "$alphabet" }
  }},
  { "$project": { "_id": 0 }}
])
```

Comment: Working great. Thank you.